# Using methods with variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I have a variable:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
```

I want to reverse the array:

```
array.reverse()
```

In that example I didn't need to make a temporary variable like this:

```
var arrayRev = array.reverse()
```

or like this:

```
var array = array.reverse()
```

but some times I need to make a temporary variable with different methods.

in this example I want to join the items in the array:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
array.join("")
console.log(array)
```

The result is still `[1,2,3]` not `123`

but if I do this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var arrayJoin = array.join("")
console.log(arrayJoin)
```

or this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var array = array.join("")
console.log(array)
```

it works!

why is that so, and how do I know whether to use this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
var array = array.join("")
console.log(array)
```

or this:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
array.join("")
console.log(array)
```

thanks!

Comment: `array.join` returns a new string. It does not mutate `array`. Additionally strings in JavaScript are immutable, so all string methods (actually function-properties) return new strings rather than mutating the subject string in-place.

Comment: *how do I know when to use* By reading the documentation

Comment: [mdn doc for array instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods)

Comment: You look at the documentation. (As you get more experienced with JavaScript, you’ll learn that some behaviours, like changing an array into a string in place, are impossible, but apart from those you still look at the documentation.)